# File size limit for extending ADFs?

Tags: google-project-tango

I made a few experiments with extending ADFs and discovered an apparent file size limit for extending ADFs.

All ADFs larger than around 60MB would cause the Tango Service to stop, after some time I get a TangoErrorException in my own app and a Screen showing "Faild to connect to Tango. Please restart application" with Tango Explorer.

This occured with multiple ADFs, some where already extended once or even twice, others were als large as 130MB and recorded in on go.

I can't find any mention about this in the official documentation.

My impression is, that there might be some kind of timeout when the Tango service is starting, and larger ADFs take longer to load/reopen.
But this is just a theory based on the fact the time between starting the Service and the error seems to be about the same, no matter the file size.

Using the same ADfs just for localization works find.

Can anybody confirm this issue or even has a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: Have you found any workaround to this issue? I'm having the same trouble. It may not be due to a timeout because AreaDescriptionManager (one of the sample apps) warns "Tango service has crashed" right as the application starts loading those files.

Comment: I haven't found a workaround, but I did some timing with a few different ADFs, and it was almost allways almost exactly 10 seconds between calling .connect() and the resulting exception. In a few cases it was 1.5 seconds.

Comment: I think I support your observation; please ignore my last comment. I went through 3 files and got about 10 seconds in every case. I watched memory allocation of each file using AreaDescriptionManager (closing the app as it crashes and reading the small pop-up that tells you how much ram was freed) and saw a unique size in each case; if this means that these files were loaded completely, that'd support that file size doesn't matter, as you've mentioned. Then probably the cause is the timeout.

Comment: Found an issue posted on the Git repository of Tango Unity samples: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/issues/80 I summarized our observation and linked this post. I hope this fastens something.

Comment: According to a support in the thread, "extending existing building-scale area descriptions is not a supported use case". His suggested workaround is essentially not a workaround.